VSCode highlight .tikz file similar to .tex
Is there a way to enable the same syntax highlighting from a .tex file for a .tikz file?
When the tikz code is written inside a latex-document the highlighting with the Latex-Workshop extensions works well, but for readability many tikzpictures are in a seperate .tikz file and just included into the latex chapter-files.
Is there a way to tell VSCode, that it should apply the same highlighting as for a latex file?
In summary: it should trade the .tikz file as a .tex file.

You can configure VSCode to apply the same syntax highlighting for .tikz files as it does for .tex files.
Associating File Types
To achieve this, you can associate the .tikz file extension with LaTeX in your VSCode settings. Here's how:

Open the Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P or Cmd + Shift + P on macOS);
Search for Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON) and select it;
In the settings.json file, add the following configuration to associate .tikz files with LaTeX:

"files.associations": {
    "*.tikz": "latex"
}

This configuration will instruct VSCode to treat .tikz files as LaTeX files, applying the same syntax highlighting and other features (such as autocompletion) provided by the LaTeX Workshop extension.
Working with Standalone Files
I recommend working with TikZ code in a standalone file. This helps with better organization and improves the workflow. Once the TikZ picture is complete, you can easily include it in your main LaTeX document. This approach ensures both readability and functionality, allowing LaTeX Workshop's features to continue working seamlessly.

Thank you very much, this is exactly the information I was looking for.

The information regarding standalone files is very useful. However, I mostly work with plots, which I export with Matlab2Tikz, for example. I then have these plots as .tikz files and often just want to adjust them a little, for which the highlighting is very useful.
